# When using mandrill do i need to verify domain in mailchimp as well

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

Since Mailchimp is taking over the billing and management of Mandrill accounts, does this mean that any sending domain I wish to send to via Mandrill also needs to be a verified sending domain in MailChimp?

I cannot find a clear answer on what will happen come the 27th when the legacy mandrill accounts will be suspended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need to verify in *both* Mandrill and MailChimp at this time. But depending on when your account was created, you may need to perform an additional verification step.

In Mandrill, go to the [Sending Domains](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/sending-domains) page in your account. Be sure there are **three** checkmarks for each of the sending domains you want to continue using (like the second one shown below).[image: verified domains]

If you don't see the third checkmark (like the first line), click the button (top right of the table) that says "Verify A Domain" to generate the verification email.

Comment: This is not true @Kaitlin. Mailchimp requires it's own authentication, having the Mandrill configuration is not sufficient to authorize domains in MailChimp, despite them being owned by the same company.